# How to filter data in python using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

```
list = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phonenumber']
```

I want to iterate for this list as:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

df[ pd.notnull(df[firstname]) | pd.notnull(df[lastname]) | 
    pd.notnull(df[email]) | pd.notnull(df[phonenumber])]
```

How do I perform the above process using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` using `columns` with null values.

```
df.isnull().any()
>> 
firstname True
lastname True
...

df.isnull().sum()
```

It shows all columns and the total NaNs of each column (your list).

Answer (score 0):

First, do not shadow built-in class names:

```
L = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phonenumber']
```

Then use `notnull` with `any` along `axis=1` to construct a Boolean series mask:

```
res = df[df[L].notnull().any(1)]
```